# Idrisi - how can I convert x/y into lat/long?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have coordinates (Idrisi) x: 550000, 580000 y: 4840000, 4810000, but I need latitude and longitude... how can I convert it? :(

Thanx

Comment: According to http://www.pierssen.com/idrisi/drg.htm it looks like the x,y pixels in the image map directly to lat/longs.  Would it make sense for the image you're looking at to have latitude 48.4, 48.1 as bounds, and longitude 55.0 and 58.0 as bounds?

Comment: This page might help as well: http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/ecosys/cdroms/ged_iia/html/gis.htm#idrisi .  This one too: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_Idrisi.html . According to that, there should be a .ref file with geographic reference information.

Comment: If you ask a poor question, you can expect to get poor answers.  Shrug.  Good luck.